# Programmatically creating servlet path and variables with Jetty

Tags: rest, servlets, jax-rs, embedded-jetty, path-variables

I'd like to be able to programmatically register servlet context paths with variables in Jetty, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in Jetty by itself.

There are a few requirements that are making it difficult:

1. I have to use Maven for dependency management.
2. I have to use a specific subclass of javax.servlet.Filter for authentication.

Given the conflicts with the existing environment, nifty stuff like Play! and Grails are out, and even though the JAX-RS annotations are neat, I'd to be able to programmatically change these things around in a config file without recompiling.

Basically I'm looking for routes management similar to http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/routes, but I can't figure out a starting point to get going in that direction.

I can use any embedded server I need, as long as I adhere to the above, which unfortunately means I don't think I can use something like http://code.joejag.com/2011/creating-a-simple-java-restful-service-using-jersey-and-maven/.

Given Jetty, I'd picture the code looking something like this:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);

ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");
server.setHandler(context);
// add other random stuff to the context
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ThingServlet()),"/things/{id}");
// the above line could easily come from a config file using Class.forName, etc. 
server.start();
server.join();
```

I'm completely open to suggestions, embedded web servers, whatever. I'm used to writing more in Django/Pylons/Werkzeug with their routing and I got thrown into this a few days ago and this is what I have to work with so far, so any guidance or assistance would be appreciated!